# Unit or (Left/right zero) divisior

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R is finite Ring with 1 and $a \in R \setminus \{0\}$. Show that a is Unit or (Left/right) zero divisior
It's obvious that we have to use the mapping: $x \rightarrow ax$ and $x \rightarrow xa$ but what else?

Comment: **Hint**: the mapping you wrote is injective if and only if it's surjective.

Comment: Also: be careful that you need an extra argument to show that $a$ has a left-side inverse if and only if it has a right-side inverse, in the noncommutative case.

Comment: I added the "ring theory" tag; hope that's OK with you.  Cheers!

Comment: Please use the search feature before asking.